# Move a directory to one-level up of batch file's directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to move my files (along with sub-folders) from `%LocalAppdata%\A` directory to `B\App\D` directory.
The batch file resides in `B\Bat` directory. I currently do the following to copy files from 
`%LocalAppdata%\A` to `B\App\D` --

```
MOVE /Y "%LocalAppData%\A\*.*" "%~dp0..\App\D"
```

*(Note that the folder `B` is a variable, so I just can't use it)*

The above doesn't seem to move the sub-folders .

Comment: I don't understand why you are having a problem. That MOVE command works fine for me. Are you sure the App\D folder exists when the command fails?

Comment: @dbenham Sorry, the original code also works but was not able to move sub-folders with files. I will update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MOVE and RENAME can work with multiple files using wild cards in the source mask. They can also work with individual folders. But they cannot work with multiple folders using wild cards in the source mask.

So you can move the folders individually using a loop, and then move all the remaining files directly with a wild card.

```
for /d %%F in ("%LocalAppData%\A\*") do move /y "%%F" "%~dp0..\App\D"
move /y "%LocalAppData%\A\*" "%~dp0..\App\D"
```

Or simply move everything individually with one loop. The only draw back with this is it can fail if there is unicode in your file/folder names that does not map to the active code page. It is also a bit less efficient, but I don't think that is significant.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%LocalAppData%\A\*"') do move /y "%LocalAppData%\A\%%F" move /y "%%F" "%~dp0..\App\D"
```

One advantage of this last approach is you can add the `/A` option to the `dir` command (do not follow with attributes) and move *all* files and folders, including those with the hidden and/or system attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Set the working directory to the parent.

```
pushd "%~dp0.." && MOVE /Y "%LocalAppData%\A\*.*" ".\App\D\"
```

Comment: It works but how will I able to move sub-folders with files too. My    %LocalAppdata%\A\ folder contains files and sub-folders too. The `Move` command doesn't seem to work with sub-folders.

Comment: xcopy doesn't seem to work. `xcopy "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome" "%~dp0..\App\User\Local\Appdata\Google\Chrome" /E`

Comment: @AviAryan  See DBenham's answer for moving both files and folders.  I will leave my answer as is for moving just files since that was the original question.